# How to color parts' title background in TOC with tocloft?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, tocloft

As you can guess from the title, I am using the package `tocloft` to customize the table of contents of a document, which, by the way, I am compiling with LuaTeX.

The final result that I would like to get can be simplified as follows:

[image: desired TOC]

The feature that I am not able to implement on my own is the black background of the part title. Please ignore the other design features of the picture I have posted that may differ from the standard latex TOC (e.g. the missing page number).

Do you know how can I achieve such look? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into `titletoc`, it allows to use `\colorbox` without hacks.

If you really want to keep using `tocloft` you can use a hack: Capture the title in a `\hbox`, which you `\unhbox` later in the colorbox:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,xcolor}
\newcommand\cftafterparttitle{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{1pt}\colorbox{black}{\unhbox0}\egroup%
}
\expandafter\renewcommand
  \expandafter\cftpartfont
  \expandafter{\cftpartfont
    \color{white}%
    \setbox0\hbox\bgroup
      \aftergroup\cftafterparttitle
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Teil 1}
\chapter{Kapitel 1}
\section{Abschnitt 1}
\part{Teil 2}
\chapter{Kapitel 2}
\section{Abschnitt 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works perfectly! thanks.
I think I am going to keep using `tocloft` simply because I have some other customized features which I do not have time to move to `titletoc`. Would you in general suggest, for the next times, to move to `titletoc`?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with either of them to give a really qualified recommendation, but it looks like `titletoc` is probably better if you not only just want to change some details. For small changes there is a significant advantage for `tocloft` through: You can change some separated settings instead of having to change all parameters at one go.